# Installer for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, templates, wix, installation

I need to create a setup for installing my project. I meant to try both WIX both native visual studio installer, but i don't know how, when i go to new project there isn't such option. I figured out that WIX don't add templates on 2010, but why there isn't one for visual studio installer? [image: projects]
I would also like to know if there are any other simple installers worth trouble?

Comment: Is that VS2010 Express? Express versions cannot build installers or deployment projects. Consider ClickOnce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 was the last version to support Visual Studio Installer (.vdproj) projects. Many teams use WiX Toolset instead. [UPDATE: There is now a VS extension that provides Visual Studio Installer support to later versions.]

WiX Toolset is a Visual Studio extension. Express versions don't allow extensions so that might be a reason you don't see templates. Another reason is that for the WiX installer to register templates, Visual Studio 2010 must be installed first. You can try repairing the WiX installation.

Another IDE for WiX is SharpDevelop. (It's free.)

Both Visual Studio Installer and WiX Toolset create Windows Installer packages. It's important to understand what Windows Installer does. If you are trying them to compare them, you might be interested in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15268613/2226988).

NSIS is another technology entirely. It gives complete control over what's put the target system, including whether to have an uninstaller at all. Many projects use it as a bundler for Windows Installer packages. (But, note that WiX now has a bundler [called burn].)

Comment: **Note:** Microsoft has decided to bring back the Visual Studio Installer project for Visual Studio 2013 due to popular demand. **[Announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx)** - [Download](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Thanks for the news. You'll notice in the comments on the announcement that a fair number of people prefer WiX once they have learned enough about it and Windows Installer. But for those that are now not forced to rewrite existing installers, this is good news.